# Wordpress rewrite table plugin

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I'm looking for a solution to rewrite URL in Wordpress site, in such way to keep it compatible with the previous website.

So, with the following code:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^whatever/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

... Wordpress will redirect `/whatever/123` to `index.page?page_id=123`, but what I want is not an redirect, but to keep `whatever/123` in URL. In this case, redirection works and URL became permalink from Permalink Common Settings, which is not desirable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add these lines in your  .htaccess file :

```
RewriteRule ^whatever/([0-9]+)?/?([0-9]+)?/?$ /index.php?p=$1&page=$2 [QSA]
```

May this will help you ...

Comment: No, everything is the same